# iPhone backup: extracting app vs copy?

Tags: ios, backup, iphone

I'm trying to do a forensic analysis of an iPhone, saving a backup which is as raw as possible.

Using iMazing, I can backup apps using <Copy to Mac>:

[image]

.or <Manage Apps: Extract App>:

[image]

**Which is the one which gives a backup that is as raw as possible?**

Indeed, why would they even produce different IPA files?

(<Extract App> produces a IPA file that contains an extra <Payload> folder, <iTunesArtwork>, and <iTunesMetadata.plist>.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be posed to [iMazing support](https://support.imazing.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Comment: @IconDaemon, I'm seeing this issue with other iPhone backup tools too. Question is: What's the proper way to do a iPhone forensic backup? Saving the first kind of IPA or the second?

Answer (score 1):

In iMazing there is multiple ways to browse backups or app data.

Here is the few possibilities:

1. Browse a specific app's backup content

[image]

2. Browse all backup's files and folders

[image]

3. Use the function "Export Raw Data" (right click the device from the sidebar and click "Export Raw Data")